# How do I make multiple style changes to only one element in the DOM sequentially without using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the the styling of an element with a function like this one

```
function changeStyle(element)
{
   element.style.color = 'red';
   element.style.marginLeft = '50px';
   element.style.opacity = 0.5

}
```

Without using `setTimeOut`, is there a way i can make the next change only after the previous change has taken effect? I tried using promises but all the changes still happen at the same time.

Comment: They are not happening at the same time. All three style changes are happening one after another. It's just happening so fast that it looks like they are applied at the same time.

Comment: [JavaScript Version Of Sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) Read This

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for an animation effect, do you have the option of using CSS instead? Your JS code could toggle a class for example, and the CSS could handle the animation (note: I'm definitely not a CSS animation expert but just want to show how you might accomplish this):

```
// JS
function changeStyle(element) {
   element.className = 'animated';
}
```

```
// CSS
@keyframes changeStyle {
  0% {
    color: red;
  }

  49% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
 
  50% {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  
  99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    color: red;
    margin-left: 50px;
    opacity: .5;
  }
}

.animated {
  animation-name: changeStyle;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle to show this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/hannahska/08v93xzy/2/